# Crystal Reports from Two DateTimePickers

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a form which contain the `CrystalReportViewer` and on the top there are two `DateTimePickers` and `button1`, When I run this code and choose the dates and click on the button, no data appear on the viewer only the columns names.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ByName cryrpt = new ByName();
     cryrpt.Load(@"C:*******************ByName.rpt");
     ParameterFields pfields = new ParameterFields();
     ParameterField pfield = new ParameterField();
     ParameterDiscreteValue pdisc = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
     ParameterField pfield1 = new ParameterField();
     ParameterDiscreteValue pdisc1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

     pfield.Name = "start_Date";
     pdisc.Value = FirstDate;
     pfield.CurrentValues.Add(pdisc);
     pfields.Add(pfield);

     pfield1.Name = "End_Date";
     pdisc1.Value = SecondDate;
     pfield1.CurrentValues.Add(pdisc1);
     pfields.Add(pfield1);
     crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt;
     crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfields;
     FirstDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
     SecondDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
     crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt;
     crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: `cryrpt.Load(@"C:*******************ByName.rpt");` what is this `*` is this supposed to be a valid path..? when you step through the code using the debugger what are the values of `FirstDate && SecondDate` are you using the debugger?

Comment: I declare it at the beginning DateTime FirstDate;
        DateTime SecondDate;          and for *, I used a valid path but I replace it here by *** to hide it

Comment: What do you expect? What is your data source?

Comment: I want the report to show the record between the Two selected dates but it shows nothing, also i add this to the code   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>. SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=StockDB;Integrated Security=True");    and nothing happened

Comment: On your last line why are you doing a Refresh()?? Try removing it?